# Count or Skip(1).Any() where I want to find out if there is more than 1 record - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I'm not sure when but I read an article on this which indicates that the usage of `Skip(1).Any()` is better than `Count()` compassion when using Entity Framework (I may remember wrong). I'm not sure about this after I saw the generated T-SQL code.

Here is the first option:

```
int userConnectionCount = _dbContext.HubConnections.Count(conn => conn.UserId == user.Id);
bool isAtSingleConnection = (userConnectionCount == 1);
```

This generates the following T-SQL code which is reasonable:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
  COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[HubConnections] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Here is the other option which is the suggested query as far as I remember:

```
bool isAtSingleConnection = !_dbContext
    .HubConnections.OrderBy(conn => conn.Id)
    .Skip(1).Any(conn => conn.UserId == user.Id);
```

Here is the generated T-SQL for the above LINQ query:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
        FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
            FROM [dbo].[HubConnections] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 1
    )  AS [Skip1]
    WHERE [Skip1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId]
        FROM ( SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent2].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
            FROM [dbo].[HubConnections] AS [Extent2]
        )  AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[row_number] > 1
    )  AS [Skip2]
    WHERE [Skip2].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1];
```

Which one is the proper way here? Is there a big performance difference between these two?

Comment: What would happen if the result has no records and you perform .Skip(1) ...., might test this out later :)

Comment: how different are the execution plans?

Comment: @Jeroen that would return what I wanted since I am only interested in if it has 1 record.

Comment: "Is there a big performance difference between these two?" - measure it!

Comment: @DStanley lazy web. sorry! and yes, I wanted to get this question out, too. That's why I asked instead of doing this by myself.

Comment: Honestly, I'd write it as expressively as possible, and worry about actual performance issues if they pop up afterwards.  if (x.Count() > 1) *reads* so much easier to me, than .Skip(1).Any().

Comment: @tugberk Two points: 1) You often can't discern performance issues just by _looking_ at code (with some obvious, well known exceptions), so the only way to get a _true_ answer is to measure it under realistic conditions, and 2) even though there might be a _faster_ way, it may not be a performance issue in your context - your app may spend 99% of it's time waiting for user input and 0.1% of it's time counting connections - in which case improving the performance is not going to significantly change the _overall user experience_

Comment: @DStanley they are all valid concerns. I just wanna see what people are doing in a case like this. No big deal :)

Comment: @Jeroen Skip() and Take() works fine if there is no items in the list. which makes them nice to use in for example strings instead of substring()

Comment: I would say that Skip(1).Any() is way faster in a large table/collection, but as previously stated the biggest problems are not solved by this kinds of performance boosts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Query performance depends on a lot of things, like the indexes that are present, the actual data, how stale the statistics about the data present are etc. SQL query plan optimizer looks at these different metrics to come up with an efficient query plan. So, any straightforward answer that says query 1 is always better than query 2 or the opposite would be incorrect.

That said, my answer below tries to explain the articles stance and how `Skip(1).Any()` could be better(marginally) than doing a `Count() > 1`. The second query though being bigger in size and mostly unreadable looks like it could be interpreted in an efficient fashion. Again, this depends on things aforementioned. The idea is that the number of rows that the database has to look into to figure out the result is more in case of `Count()`. In the count case, assuming that the required indexes are there (a clustered index on Id to make the OrderBy in second case efficient), the db has to go through count number of rows. In the second case, it has to go through a maximum of two rows to arrive at the answer.

Lets get more scientific in our analysis and see if my above theory holds any ground. For this, I am creating a dummy database of customers. The Customer type looks like this,

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I am seeding the database with some 100K random rows(I really have to prove this) using this code,

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        using (CustomersContext db = new CustomersContext())
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Customer c = new Customer
                {
                    Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Age = r.Next(0, 100)
                };
                db.Customers.Add(c);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/5454730).

Now, the queries that I am going to use are as follows,

```
db.Customers.Where(c => c.Age == 26).Count() > 1; // scenario 1

db.Customers.Where(c => c.Age == 26).OrderBy(c => c.ID).Skip(1).Any() // scenario 2
```

I have started SQL profiler to catch the query plans. The captured plans look as follows,

### Scenario 1:

Check out the estimated cost and actual row count for scenario 1 in the above images.
[image: Scenario 1 - Estimated Cost]
[image: Scenario 1 - Actual row count]

### Scenario 2:

Check out the estimated cost and actual row count for scenario 2 in the below images.
[image: Scenario 2 - Estimated Cost]
[image: Scenario 2 - Actual row count]

As per the initial guess, the estimated cost and the number of rows is lesser in the Skip and any case as compared to Count case.

### Conclusion:

All this analysis aside, as many others have commented earlier, these are not the kind of performance optimizations you should try to do in your code. Things like these hurt readability with very minimal(I would say non-existent) perf benefit. I just did this analysis for fun and would never use this as a basis for choosing scenario 2. I would measure and see if doing a `Count()` is actually hurting to change the code to use `Skip().Any()`.

Comment: Novice here. Why would one want to rely on generated queries for performance? Wouldn't it be better to write query directly, if EF supports it?

Comment: Certainly yes. If you see some query is hurting performance(may be on the hot path), you should hand optimize it. EF does support executing SQL queries directly. It also supports ESQL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you not suggest OP to use ESQL instead? Lets say ESQL doesnt have support for the scenario OP asked, why not straight SQL? I mean, when to use what is what I feel is missing. Unless its simple scenarios, the query generation/code generation looks doubtful to me :)

Answer (score 6):

> I read an article on this which indicates that the usage of `Skip(1).Any()` is better than `Count()`.

That statement is quite true *on a LINQ to objects query*.  On a LINQ to objects query `Skip(1).Any()` only needs to try to get the first two items of the sequence, and it can ignore all of the items that come after it.  If the sequence involves rather expensive operations (and properly defers execution) or even more importantly, if the sequence is infinite, this could be a big deal.  For most queries it will matter a *bit*, but often not a lot.

For a LINQ query that is based on a query provider instead it's unlikely to be significantly difference.  Particularly with EF, as you have seen, the generated query is not noticeably different.  Is it *possible* for there to be a difference, sure.  One case could be handled better than the other by the query provider, particular queries much be able to be optimized better with the particular refactor used by one or the other, etc.

If someone is suggesting that there's a major difference in the EF query between these two, odds are they're mistakenly applying the guideline that was designed to just apply to a LINQ to objects query.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely depend on your record count in your table/data set.  If you have a lot of records, then doing a count on an identity will be very fast, because it's indexed, but skipping one record and then getting the next record would be faster.

Granted, this process could be done in sub-millisecond in either case.  Unless you have a record count that exceeds 10,000+ records, it really won't matter unless you need it to return under a specific threshold.  Don't forget that SQL Server will cache query execution plans.  If you re-run the same query, you may not see a difference after running it the first time, unless the data changes pretty significantly beneath it.